# Export contact in .vcf (vcard) format Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, vcf-vcard

I want to get a contact stored in windows phone device and save in .vcf (vcard format) but I cannot find any method for this functionality.

In msdn documentation the method ParseVcardAsnc does the reverse of what I need.

Is there any method in c# for what I am looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`ToVcardAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj207483.aspx) or [`ToVcardAsync(VCardFormat)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj662978.aspx) methods.

[ContactInformation class in WindowsPhone on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.personalinformation.contactinformation.aspx)